# Create a Subdomain on AWS with Forwarding

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain

My domain is registered through GoDaddy, but I am hosting the contents using Amazon S3. I would like to create a subdomain (beta.example.com) and forward it to an IP address that is of a local physical server. However, the subdomain should show up in the browser and not the IP address.

I'm new to AWS so I am not fully aware of the server side lingo. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: Add an A record for `beta.example.com` with the right IP. Nothing to do with AWS really.

Comment: @ceejayoz In GoDaddy? I can't access the DNS Zone File settings because it says "The zone file is unavailable because the domain's set nameservers do not belong to this registrar."

Comment: @ceejayoz Is there a way to forward beta.example.com to another website? Can't seem to do it through A record because it says invalid characters.

Comment: Invalid characters? What are you putting as the IP address? It should be ###.###.###.###.

Comment: @ceejayoz You are correct. But I was wondering if I want to forward the subdomain to another http:// address instead of an IP, what do I do?

Comment: S3's website hosting can redirect a bucket to a URL. Other than that, you'd need to get a server involved.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yup, I tried that already but I would like the address bar to show the subdomain (beta.example.com). I also tried creating a CNAME record in Route 53. It seemed like it would work, but didn't.

Comment: For a CNAME to work the site you're pointing it at needs to be set up to handle `beta.example.com`.

Comment: @ceejayoz Alright, thanks so much for your guidance. Definitely cleared things up. Let me see what I can do. Back to Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, determine what DNS servers are authoritative for your domain.  You can do this by looking at the domain settings at GoDaddy.

- Go to Godaddy.com and login
- From the main menu, launch the domains control panel
- Select the domain in question by clicking on it
- On the resulting page, look at what's listed in the **nameservers** section

Once you know what nameservers are being used, you need to add a new A record to them for the subdomain you're trying to create.  I'm assuming you're using Route53 for your DNS, so:

- login to the AWS console
- select Route 53
- select the domain in question
- create a new resource record
- set record type to A
- Enter the hostname you want to create in the name box (i.e. for foo.example.com you would enter foo)
- In the value box, enter the IP address of the local server you want the subdomain to point to